# How can I show Error Page when ?error is added to URL in Spring security?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-security

The below C:if statement is not working. it is not showing the error message as expected.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
<form:form action="/Map/authenticateUser" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
<c:if test="${param.error != null}">
        
    <i class="failed">Sorry! You entered invalid username/password.</i>
                                        
    <div class="alert alert-danger col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
        Invalid username and password.</div>
                                    
</c:if>
```

I am doing this from a course and the code runs on the Instructor's side. i am repeating the same steps but not getting the output.

my pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring MVC support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <!-- spring-security-web and spring-security-config -->
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- to compensate for java 9+ not including jaxb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
            
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I dont know if I have to add different dependencies or make changes in my jsp page.
I am new to Spring security.

My LoginController class:

```
package com.mandeep.website.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    
    @GetMapping("/showMyLoginPage")
    public String showMyLoginPage() {
        
        return "fancy-login";
    }
}
```

My Main Controller class:

```
package com.mandeep.website.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class AppController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showHome() {
        
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Note: After debugging I found that the request of the Error URl is going as GET method. If anyone knows how to set it to POST method because Spring security uses POST.

[image]

Comment: You should be using the `<form:errors/>` tag. Also, check if are you passing a param object in your modal.

Comment: how do i check the param object?

Comment: Please add the code of your controller class.

Comment: Done i have two controller classes and added them both